# HOW TO GET LOCATION DETAILS OF A PARTICULAR USER (may be a non-friend) in facebook through GRAPH API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

actually I need to know the procedure of getting all the check-ins or the location details that is issued by a particular user (who may be a non-friend to me) in his every post that contains location information though Graph API. Thanks in advance. I've gone through https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/feed https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/post references upto now.

Comment: I am not asking for the code, all I need is the reference of any of such procedures.

Answer (score 0):

For obvious reasons (privacy and stuff) you can´t get the location details (=checkins) of any user. You can ONLY get it by authorizing a User with the correct permission and ONLY for that authorized User.

Although, i am not sure if it´s even possible anymore to get the checkins even for the authorized User - because the checkin endpoint is deprecated.